# PhP MultiDimensional Array fetching

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I am not really familiar on how php handles array, in **.NET** I can access array using this method

```
array[x][y];
```

My question is:

I am retrieving records from the database and returning it to the `$res_merchant_field`

```
$res_merchant_field = $this->CI->merchantfield_model->merchantfield_list( $str_where );
```

and `$res_merchant_field` will be populated with this record:

```
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [MFID] => 1
            [MFName] => Bill No
            [FTID] => 1
            [DTID] => 1
            [MFRequired] => 1
            [MFDefaultValue] => 
            [MFDueDate] => 0
            [MFToBePaid] => 0
            [MFMaxLength] => 12
            [MFOrderNo] => 1
            [MFStatus] => 1
        )

    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [MFID] => 2
            [MFName] => Gallons Consumed
            [FTID] => 1
            [DTID] => 2
            [MFRequired] => 1
            [MFDefaultValue] => 
            [MFDueDate] => 0
            [MFToBePaid] => 0
            [MFMaxLength] => 5
            [MFOrderNo] => 2
            [MFStatus] => 1
        )

    [2] => stdClass Object
        (
            [MFID] => 3
            [MFName] => Amount Due
            [FTID] => 3
            [DTID] => 1
            [MFRequired] => 1
            [MFDefaultValue] => 
            [MFDueDate] => 0
            [MFToBePaid] => 1
            [MFMaxLength] => 15
            [MFOrderNo] => 3
            [MFStatus] => 1
        )

)
```

How can I access and fetch the record from that array with this condition:

1. it will look through all the array find specific index, lets say index 0 which is MFID,
2. after getting the MFID and comparing it with another variable, if it is true,
3. it will get the DTID for that array MFID.

example:

get MFID = 1, the DTID will be 1, if I get the MFID = 3, the DTID will be 1.

or how can I access the array like `$array[x][y]`?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the second level is not an array but instead an object, to access a property you will have to use this format.

```
 $array[$x]->$y;
```

Unfortunately you cannot access a property by an index do o get the MFID of the 0th Item you will need to say

```
 $array[0]->MFID;
```

Comment: Hi again Orangepill, this is a follow up question though, nearly the same question as above, I have managed to solve the initial problem, now I am producing this kind of array:

Array
(
[0] => Array
(
[0] => 11
[1] => 123
[2] => 232.22
)

[1] => Array
(
[0] => 1
[1] => 2
[2] => 3
)

)

I tried the method

$validate_field[0]->0;

but it doesnt work.

thanks again.

Comment: now it is an array of arrays and you can use the [$x][$y] notation. The tell here is in the original question the `stdClass Object` in the var dump

Comment: hm.. I seem to have solve the question, I can access the array using
$validate_field[0][0]. That is weird though, how come I can access and get the value from that array using $array[$x][$y] compare to my first question that must use $validate_field[0]->MFID?

Comment: the first problem was an array or objects, the follow up was an array of arrays.

Comment: how can I determine whether an array of arrays or if it is an array of objects? so php treats these kind of data seperately? interesting..